# How to set background-image to take remaining section of the page in semantic-ui

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I am trying to set a background-image in my content area. HTML pages containes 3 main section. Header, Content and Footer. So I am use following code for this. Content is not displaying the whole background image rather it is displaying according to the content inside it. How can this content take the whole remaining space. I am new to css and front-end framework.

Here is the code.

```
<div class="ui container">
    <div class="ui large secondary inverted menu">
            <div class="item">
                Our Company
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui landing-image fluid container">

        <h1 class="ui inverted header">Hello</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="ui inverted vertical footer segment">

        <div class="ui container">
            Footer
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.landing-image {
  background-image: url("/assets/images/black.png") !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
}
```

Here is the working pen. http://codepen.io/next1/pen/WxLRPv

Comment: set a height on the landing-image class, please create a fiddle and link it and we can help you! :)

Comment: @Medda86 Codepen link added. :)

Comment: @nextt1 The height of your sections is equal to the height of you content at the moment. Set the height of the landing-image container explicitly if you want to look it different, or add some padding: http://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/XKorNE

Comment: @Deka87 I can add `height=100%` but it will make my page scrollable. So how do I avoid that ?

Comment: @nextt1, well if you have 3 sections, each of those must be maximum 33% if you want to avoid vertical scrolling. Make sure to specify the height of html and body to 100% then.

Comment: @Deka87 Thanks. I guess that will solve my probelm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? :)
https://jsfiddle.net/eaxjmduf/

html

```
<header>header</header>
<main>main</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

css

```
html,body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}

header, footer{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  background:#333;
}

main {
  width:100%;
  min-height:calc(100% - 100px);
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1446080501695-8e929f879f2b?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=725&ixjsv=2.0.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1225');;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I implemented in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply *flexbox* to the wrapping `div`:

```
.parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Then just apply a `flex-grow: 2` to the element you want to stretch.

Here's a working [pen](http://codepen.io/akhanov/pen/RREpjw)